# single.php for taxonomy slug

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Hi there I am trying to open a specific single.php if specific "slugs" are forwarded from my taxonomy.

I did this with author:

```
<?php $post = $wp_query->post;
if(get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $post->post_author) == 'name') {
/* Do your author-specific work */
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-coupon-1.php');
} else {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-coupon-2.php');
}
?>
```

but i need this for my taxonomy

my taxonomy is

```
<?php echo appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'slug'); ?>
```

now if the slug is (just an example) "amazon" the single-coupon-2.php should be used.

I tryed a lot but always getting errors! And right now I am lost in confusion ;-)...

Thanks and any help is appreciated!

Comment: still lost tryed almost everything, is there nobody with an idea

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood your question, but WordPress provides a [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) so you can create templates for specific pages.

Just create a taxonomy-myslug.php in your theme file and WordPress will pick it out automatically.

If there is commonality between different templates, use [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to ensure you only code once.

Comment: yes i think you did, I have a taxonomy "appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy" and it provides me with a store name anytime I use the above php. I would like to archive is, that if the single.php (i use single-coupon.php for this and the taxonomy includes the slug (store name) like amazon it should open single-coupon-1.php instead of single-coupon-2.php (the standard single.php for this taxonomy). Sorry but english is not my first language....